# how to display a rally "custom board" dashboard in confluence wiki

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I have been digging in the this site and others for several days and the answer to my problem still escapes me.
I have read all of these pages:
  http://pastebin.com/cbagkw8h
but none of them exactly answers this question:
I am trying to get a Rally Dashboard (custom board) to appear in HTML/Javascript in a confluence wiki.  I have gotten a simple Standard Report working using a read-only account and AppSDK1.32 with loginKey by embedding the following HTML/Javascript into the Confluence wiki page:

```
{html} 
<meta name="Name" content="App Example: Rally Application" /> 
<meta name="Version" content="2011.04" /> 
<meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software" /> 
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.32/sdk.js?loginKey=loginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkey"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function onLoad() { 
var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource( 
    '__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
    '__PROJECT_OID__', 
    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__'); 
rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.destroy(); 
var reportConfig = {report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.IterationBurndown,
    width : 400, height: 300};
var report = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(reportConfig); 
report.display("reportDiv"); 
} 
rally.addOnLoad(onLoad); 
</script> 
<div id="reportDiv" style="width: 400px; margin-left:20px"></div> 
<br/> 
{html}
```

I am trying to expand this success to an entire dashboard with App SDK2.x using the new apiKey - by using the following code:

```
{html} 
<meta name="Name" content="App Example: Rally Application" /> 
<meta name="Version" content="2015.04" /> 
<meta name="Vendor" content="eBay Enterprise" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://loginapirally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.32/sdk.js?loginKey=loginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkeyloginkey">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function onLoad() { 
rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.destroy(); 
document.getElementById("iframeA").width = screen.width - 60 ; 
document.getElementById("iframeA").height = (screen.width - 60 ) * 3; 
} 
rally.addOnLoad(onLoad); 
</script> 
<iframe id="iframeA" src="https://loginapirally1.rallydev.com/#/111111111d/custom/222222222?expandApp=333333333&apiKey=_apikeyapikeyapikeyapikeyapikeyapikeyapikey" width="1024" height="1024">
</iframe> 
<br/> 
{html}
```

I am noticing a few things:

1) it almost works - I get the dashboard/report title but not the cards

2) the apiKey seems to have no affect at all - I still get prompted for a login and password (which I could stand if I could see the cards).

3) it doesn't seem to matter if I put the apiKey before or after the hash symbol

Citation A suggested using the "full screen" dashboard/report but didn't cover the apiKey.

Citaton B says that the AppSDK2 uses the apiKey as of Apr 14 2014 but doesn't say how to use it exactly with AppSDK2.

I have gotten the apiKey to work with the Ruby API but it is unclear how to access the dashboard/reports from there.

Citation C says that the AppSDK1 is based on the Javascript dojo framework and the AppSDK2 is based on the Javascript Sencha's ExtJS but avoids giving any kind of rosetta stone from one to the other.

The only other options I can think of is to 1) copy the entire HTML page-source from the "Custom Board" and then start debugging the Javascript with ExtJS (but I cannot find an example of where to put the apiKey for ExtJS) or 2) bypass all of the APIs and use Ruby Watir-Webdriver (which uses 
Selenium) and VNCServer to clip an image of the "Custom Board" page and show THAT in confluence.

Citations: http://pastebin.com/YMUEPjSF

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be specific to the canned Custom Board that cannot be loaded externally. It should work if you write a js source code to build a similar Board and compile that into a deployment html. That is similar to option (1) you mentioned in the end of your post if I understand it correctly.

Here is my test where I compared Custom Board and Custom HTML side by side.

Below is a screenshot from Rally. This custom dashboard has Custom Board on the left and Custom HTML on the right. The Custom HTML is using a code [example of filterable board](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/filterable-grid-board) from AppSDK2 documentation.

[image]

Next I use this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Custom Grid</title>
    <meta name="Name" content="App: Custom Dashboard"/>
<meta name="Version" content="2011.08.31"/>
<meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Labs, NickM"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.32/sdk.js?loginKey=c33e83...."></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 rally.addOnLoad(function() {

                var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                iframe.src = "https://loginapirally1.rallydev.com/#/14018981229/custom/34207853894" 
                iframe.width = 2000;
                iframe.height = 1000;
                document.getElementById("storyboard").appendChild(iframe);

});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="storyboard"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the dashboard loaded externally on `localhost:3000`. The left column of the dashboard where Custom Board is expected to load is empty, but the right column with a custom html code of a board loads successfully:

[image]

It looks like the canned Custom Board cannot be loaded externally but a custom html code written in AppSDK2 can be displayed externally.

A couple of observations:

There is really no upgrade path from AppSDK1 to AppSDK2. The underlying frameworks and the class structures are very different and the code cannot be simply refactored. There is no  translation from one to the other.

LoginKey is intended to work with AppSDK1. Both are legacy. Both predate AppSDK2 and ApiKey. To use ApiKey with custom html apps written with AppSDK2  see ["Use API Key with  AppSDK2"](https://rallydev.force.com/answers?id=kA014000000PQZwCAO) article.

AppSDK2 does not support LoginKey usage for authentication. The reason it seems to work in this example is that we load the entire page. Loading the entire page using iframe's src property is possible with LoginKey. In this example there is no reason to use ApiKey and LoginKey together. You are right that ApiKey makes no difference in this use case.

The way LoginKey works is that it "tricks" the browser into thinking that there  is this different server, loginapirally1.rallydev.com. If you look in Network tab of your browser and see that request comes from there it means that LoginKey is working. ApiKey works differently. There is no equivalent to loginapirally1 server with ApiKey.

If you are being prompted to supply login credentials when using LoginKey it means that LoginKey is not working. See "[LoginKey Troublshooting](https://rallydev.force.com/answers?id=kA1a0000000Yalc)" article.

Embedding custom AppSDK2 apps in 3rd party portals (running custom apps externally) is possible with  ApiKey, and the supported scenario    described in [this guide](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps) is similar to the option (1) you mentioned in the end of your post. Loading entire Rally page or entire Rallynavigation is not a supported use case even though it is possible with LoginKey.